# Фрэймворк Aforge Библиотека AForge.Video.FFMPEG

Tags: c#, aforge

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день. заказчику все сроки просрочил. Работаю с фреймвокром Aforge, его библиотекой AForge.Video.FFMPEG. Но вот происходит ситуация как на картинке, все библиотеки в рабочем каталоге, ссылки в проекте установлены. Но ошибка такая продолжается. Привожу текст кода

```
private void MakeMiniVideo(string filename)
    {
        using (var writer = new VideoFileWriter())
        {
            // create new video file
            writer.Open(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), filename + "_output.avi"), 320, 270, 30, VideoCodec.Raw);
            for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
            {
                using (var img = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(filename))
                {
                    writer.WriteVideoFrame(img);
                    VideoFilesP.Add(filename, new FileVideoSource(filename + "_output.avi"));
                    //new FileVideoSource(checkedListBoxMedia.Items[checkedListBoxMedia.Items.IndexOf(checkedListBoxMedia.Items[i])].ToString())
                }
            }
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
```

При компиляции никаких ошибок. Огромное спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Вероятно проблема в том, что вы собираете проект под Any CPU. Попробуйте переключится на x86.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: К сожалению. тоже самое

Comment: К сожалению, пока это осталось загадкой